# How to bypass login procedure in XMPP Openfire server using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xmpp, openfire

I want to bypass the login procedure in XMPP. My XMPP client is JSXC and XMPP server is Openfire. I want to implent this browser based chat in php website.

Answer (score 0):

You may need SASL ANONYMOUS authentication, it may be disabled by default both in server and client, check documentation to enable it